# delete item from primary list using sharepoint designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have copied item from list A to list B based on particular field of list A.
Like if item in list A has status = resolved, item will copy to list B.

Can I do like when that particular item X get copied to list B, that item X in list A should get deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a column in List B which stores the ID of the item in List A, which was copied.Now create another SharePoint designer List workflow on List B, it will have 'Delete List Item' action which will delete the original item in List A.

[UPDATE]
Instead of using "Copy List Item" action use "Create List Item" action in SPD Workflow. Map the corresponding columns between the two lists.Also add an extra column in List B which will store the ID of List A item.
See this blog for [Create List Item using SPD workflow](http://blogs.salmanghani.info/create-item-workflow-sharepoint-designer-2010/)

Comment: Please provide the step to store ID of item from list A to list B. Also condition used in workflow to delete list A item

Comment: i have edited answer

Comment: The above step is not copying GUID from list A to list B and deleting item from list A after copy to list B

Comment: Don't copy GUID. Create List Item action has option to copy column from List A to List B. So select "ID" column of LIST A as source and select "LISTA_ID_Column" in the LIST B as target.